# Pushing shared_ptr(this) into vector results in "free(): invalid pointer" error

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, smart-pointers

I am trying to implement a class that can push a smart pointer to itself into a vector:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    void pushme(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> & vec) {
        vec.push_back(std::shared_ptr<A>(this));
    }
};

int main() {
    A test;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> vec;
    test.pushme(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles nicely, but on execution I get an `free(): invalid pointer` error. Please help me understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 9):

```
A test;
```

This declares an object in function local scope.  The object is automatically freed when it goes out of scope.

Only objects in dynamic scope (created with `new`) can be managed by `std::shared_ptr`. That's the whole purpose of `std::shared_ptr` -- to automatically call `delete` when the last shared pointer to an object goes away. And you can only `delete` something that has been allocated with `new`.

Comment: On the other hand, `shared_ptr` can hold a custom `deleter` that is responsible for freeing the object, so you could theoretically have `shared_ptr` instances that point to an object stored in automatic memory and not have `delete` called on the object when all of the `shared_ptr` instances have gone out of scope.  Not that you *should* do this, but you *can* do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this):

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>{
public:
    void pushme(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> & vec) {
        vec.push_back(shared_from_this());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> test = std::make_shared<A>();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> vec;
    test->pushme(vec);
    return 0;
}
```